How to wire smart switch with this mess:
There were originaly 4 switches in this box (left to right)

outdoor light A
outdoor light B
kitchen lights C
kitchen lights D

I want to have 1 & 2 controlled by the same smart switch
The picture depicts how they were wired - top left exposed black to the left switch, top right > right, bottom was shared between both.
All open white wires were bundled together


Same ins, same outs, switch neutrals to the neutral bundle. Did you have a more specific question? Please take the [tour].

To control both 1 & 2, A & B, with the same switch, do this:

Wire these two, top left & top right, to the output wire/screw of the smart switch:


top left exposed black to the left switch, top right > right


Wire the bottom left to the input of the smart switch:


bottom was shared between both


Wire the neutral wire of the smart switch to the bundle of white neutral wires:


All open white wires were bundled together


Get a toggle switch hole filler to fill the hole left by the removed switch, or leave the removed switch screwed to the box but without any wires attached to it.

This all works because both switches were powered by the one wire, with a jumper between the two switches, so both switches and loads are on the same circuit.
Be sure to consider wire nut size if the neutral wire from the switch goes over the existing neutral wire bundle's wire nut sizing.
Also, if the smart switch has only screws, not wires, carefully check the instructions and stamping on the switch body to see if both top left & top right output wires can go under the same screw. If there are not instructions saying you can put two wires under the one screw, then you need a pigtail of black wire and another wire nut. Wire the pigtail to the output screw, then the top wires to the pigtail under a wire nut.
